# hook_form_alter - values are not getting saved to db

Tags: 8, database, entities, forms

In entity, created a form display field using `baseFieldDefinitions`

```
$field['blood_type'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('list_string')
                       ->setLabel('Select the blood type:')
                       ->setSettings(['allowed_values' => array(1 => 'A+ve', 2 => 'o+ve')]);
```

Now in some other custom module, I alter its state using `hook_form_alter`

```
$form['blood_type_fieldset']['report_fieldset'] = array(
          '#type' => 'fieldset',
          '#title' => t('<b>blood report</b>'),
          '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
             ':input[name="blood_type"]' => array(
                array('value' => 2),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          '#collapsible' => TRUE, 
          '#collapsed' => FALSE,
          '#weight' => 5,
        );
        $form['blood_type_fieldset']['report_fieldset']['report'] = array(
          '#type' => 'radios',
          '#options' => array('report1' => 'Report 1', 'report2' => 'Report 2'),
          '#default_value' => 1,
          '#weight' => 0,
        );
```

Now as shown, there are 2 radio buttons named `A+ve` and `O+ve`. When I select O+ve, my hook_form_alter gets called up and using `#form_states`, I get fieldset as shown in code.

Now happens what is, When I initially submit my form, only db field coming from original form gets populated. Means, radio button value O+ve get saved to db, and the report radios which I have selected doesn't get saved to db.

And when second time, I click on edit form, and re-entered values `report 1` (say), then it gets saved to db.

Is the reason behind it is `hook_form_alter()`? Why `#form_states` is not allowed to be saved on first hit of submit button?

Comment: What is `#form_states`? `$form_states` or `#states`?

Comment: How are you processing/*validating* the form element value from the additional form element you have added in your form alter? If you do not have an element validate, process or submit, then this is expected behavior because the entity form is not going to know or do anything with additional form state added by form alter that is not entity related.

Comment: @Jimmy Ko It is `#states`.

Comment: @mradcliffe yes, you are right entity form is not going to know or do anything with additional form state added by form alter that is not entity related. Can you suggest any alternative for this? How can I process these additional elements added to form.

Comment: Because elements get saved on edit mode means on first submit only original form state values get saved to database additional elements added using form_alter get saved to database when I again visit the same form in editing mode.